# How can I add a lightbox handle to each image coming out of a database request please

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

If I have:

```
<div class="feed-container">
    <div id="instafeed"></div>
</div>
```

and I am calling images from a database into that div id "instafeed",
how can I add a rel or class to each image coming out of the database.

I used to do things like, "for each..." in PHP but I am not sure how to do it with html or js.
I could use PHP if that makes it easier but my knowledge of PHP and JavaScript is limited.

My main goal above is that when images are retrieved from a database, I want each image that is retrieved to have a class or del added to it so that I can use a lightbox JS to lightbox each image.

UPDATE:

What would you write if you didn't have access to the database but you new that the database would display all the images in  tags. For example, you didn't have access to the database and you are not sure if it is mysql or whatever, but you know that the database will end up displaying the images like this:

```
<a href="whatever path">image1</a>
<a href="whatever path">image2</a>
<a href="whatever path">image3</a>
<a href="whatever path">image4</a>
```

Thank you

Comment: How are you outputting the image tags?

Comment: What you have tried yet????

Comment: How are you outputting the images? via PHP or JavaScript? Could you paste what you've tried so far?

Comment: This question is too broad, does not show any attempts at solutions, and does not include enough information for anyone to give a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do it with jQuery alone, once you have retrieved the images from the database you would do this -

```
$('#instafeed img').addClass('db-img');
```

With pure JavaScript -

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var i;

for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].className += " db-img"; // note the space before the class name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you control the PHP code that fetching the images from the DB and rendering them to the HTML page, so what is the problem? I can't see any..

On the fly, add (however you want) a `class` attribute, just like `class='db-img'` to the `img` tags that you are about to render with the URL/SRC which just fetched from the DB.

For example:

```
<?php
$imageId = intval($_GET["id"]);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT img FROM images WHERE id = ". $imageId);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$mime = "image/jpeg";

$b64Src = "data:".$mime.";base64," . base64_encode($row["img"]);
echo '<img src="'.$b64Src.'" alt="" class="db-img"  />'; // NOTE to the class
?>
```

Comment: Thanks that solves this problem in this circumstance. Also, what would you write if you didn't have access to the database but you new that the database would display all the images in <a> tags. For example, you didn't have access to the database and you are not sure if it is mysql or whatever, but you know that the database will end up displaying the images like this:

<a href="whatever path">image1</a>
<a href="whatever path">image2</a>
<a href="whatever path">image3</a>
<a href="whatever path">image4</a>